# Pandas - Combine even/odd columns and aggregate by hour

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So I have a device which provides me the footfall count (in and out). It generates a csv based on number of lines drawn. The csv format is like:

`timestamp, in, out`

The above case is for if i have only 1 line. However, I am getting several in/out per row, with this format:

`timestamp, in, out, in, out, in, out, in, out`

Example of input:

```
12/01/2020,16:02:00,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,16:03:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,16:04:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,16:05:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,17:06:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,17:07:06,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,17:08:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,17:09:01,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
12/01/2020,18:10:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,18:11:00,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I wish to calculate the total sum of `in` and `out` on each hour. 
The result should be in the format:

`timestamp, ins, outs`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: More simply, could you provide an example of the input?

Comment: ```12/01/2020,16:02:00,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,16:03:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,16:04:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,16:05:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,16:06:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,16:07:06,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,16:08:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,16:09:01,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,16:10:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/01/2020,16:11:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Do all rows have the same number of elements? (in your example it is always 4)

Comment: Yes. All rows have same number of elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading `my_csv_file.csv`, you should add the corresponding in/out columns, create a timestamp column and group by the timestamp at hour level:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read file, no header!
df = pd.read_csv('my_csv_file.csv', header=None)
n_cols = len(df.columns)

# Sum all inputs and outputs
df['in'] = df.iloc[:,range(2,n_cols ,2)].sum(axis=1)
df['out'] = df.iloc[:,range(3,n_cols ,2)].sum(axis=1)
df = df.drop(columns=range(2,n_cols))

# Create a timestamp with the date and hour
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime((df[0] + ' ' + df[1]))
df =df.drop(columns=[0,1])

# Groupby same hour and same date and sum
df_grouped = df.groupby([df.timestamp.dt.date, df.timestamp.dt.hour], group_keys=False).sum()

# Prettify the output
df_grouped.index.names = ['date', 'hour']
df_grouped = df_grouped.reset_index()

#         date  hour  in  out
#0  2020-12-01    16   0    2
#1  2020-12-01    17   1    1
#2  2020-12-01    18   1    0
```

---

*Note: to recreate the data I used for the example you can use this line of code (in replacement of the `read_csv`)*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: {0: '12/01/2020', 1: '12/01/2020', 2: '12/01/2020', 3: '12/01/2020', 4: '12/01/2020', 5: '12/01/2020', 6: '12/01/2020', 7: '12/01/2020', 8: '12/01/2020', 9: '12/01/2020'}, 1: {0: '16:02:00', 1: '16:03:00', 2: '16:04:00', 3: '16:05:00', 4: '17:06:00', 5: '17:07:06', 6: '17:08:00', 7: '17:09:01', 8: '18:10:00', 9: '18:11:00'}, 2: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 1}, 3: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 4: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 5: {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 6: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 7: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 8: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 9: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 0}})
```

Comment: I get the idea but the problem is that on my end, i don't know for how many lines are there. If there is one line, there is only 1 in and out. if there are 2 lines, there are in, out, in and out. I want a generic case where the system should be able to determine the number of lines based on the extra columns it gets.

Comment: According to this, do your rows have different size inside the same file? Or do you have different files for these cases (one or several files where there is only one `in` and one `out`, one or several files with two `in` and two `out`, etc..)?

Comment: One device generates one csv. It depends upon the device for how many lines are there. I might have 1 line in device 'abc' and will have 1 column for in and 1 for out in the csv generated by that device. Now another device may heve 3 lines. The csv generated from this device will have 3 ins and 3 outs columns like (Date, Time, In, out, In, out, In, out)

Comment: Edited, try now!

Comment: '[10 11] not found in axis' if there are 10 columns (date, time, in, out, in, out, in, out, in, out)

Comment: Are you sure there are no more columns in the file? I tested it with 10 columns and it worked on my side. Can you then post an example of these 10 columns? How many columns is the maximum?

Comment: Thanks. It worked as i added `df = df.drop(columns=range(2,len(df.columns)-2))`. The problem was that additional 2 columns were added to the dataframe and we wanted to keep them. So i added a '-2' so the newly added columns are not effected.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following code. Explanation for each line has been commented.

```
df=pd.read_csv(path_here,sep=",",header=None)
df=df.rename(columns={0:"date",1:"timestamp"})


#Get all headers that are not timestamp and date 
headers=list(df.columns)
headers.remove("timestamp")
headers.remove("date")

# Unpivot data so each value is in single record
df=df.melt(id_vars=["date","timestamp"],value_vars=headers,var_name="type",value_name="value")

# Change data type for aggregation (even is in and odd is out)
df["type"]=df["type"].apply(lambda x: "in" if x%2==0 else "out")

# group by timestamp,type and find the sum of value
df=df.groupby(["date","timestamp","type"],as_index=False)["value"].sum()

# pivot table to get in and out of single time stamp in a record
df=df.pivot_table(index=["date","timestamp"],columns="type",values="value")
df=df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that the columns are unnamed. Header is basically none. So the line `headers=[i for i in df.columns if ("in" in i) or ("out" in i)]
` will generate an error as 'int' is not itratable.

Comment: Edited to match the requirement.